# ExifLib fails to install from NuGet

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, exiflib

All I want is to use the  ExifLib.dll in a Windows Phone 7.1 project. I tried to install the package from NuGet and I get a compatibility error:

> Could not install package 'ExifLib 1.3.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone71', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I am using Visual Studio 2012. Why is this happening? Is there any compatibility issue, and if it is, how could it be resolved?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common ExifLib isn't compatible with Windows Phone. But you can read this [article](http://igrali.com/2011/11/01/reading-and-displaying-exif-photo-data-on-windows-phone/)
and try this [library](http://storage2.timheuer.com/WindowsPhoneApplication63.zip) by Tim Heuer.

Answer (score 2):

[ExifLib](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/exiflib.aspx) has just been updated to version 1.4, and it now works with Windows Phone - you'll need to use the new constructor overload which takes a `Stream`.

The [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/exiflib) package has also been updated to contain a Windows Phone compatible DLL.

Comment: @Kyle, will do. Stay tuned!

Comment: @Kyle, the nuget package has been updated with support for universal apps. Please get back to me when you've given it a go!